# Unable to trigger the bind the event

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out why this event not triggered after multiple times trying with different ways. All I want is to bind my event with the change of value of FIRST INPUT text box through drop down menu Category Name. Means when I select "A or B or C " from "Category list " than that will updated to "First Input" and the event will trigger by the change of value of "First Input".

But I'm stuck and only able when I press some key on text field of "First Input" but that's not my requirement. My [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/L0vrz9vs/3/) is here and the piece of code is given below.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="col-md-3">  
                    <label>CategoryName</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="cat_id" id="cat_id">
                        <option>A</option>
                        <option>B</option>
                        <option>C</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
            FIRST Input<input type="text" name="take" id="take" class="form-control" placeholder="Take Value"  />  
                        </div> 
      <div class="col-md-4">
          Give Output<input type="text" name="give" id="give" class="form-control" placeholder="Give Value" />  
     </div>                   
     <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){  
                     $(function(){
                      $('body').on('click','#cat_id',function(){

                          var s     =$('#cat_id').val();
                          var n = s.lastIndexOf(",");
                          var s2 = s.substring(n + 1);
                          $('#take').val(s2);
                      })
                  });
                   $('#take').bind('input selectionchange propertychange',function(){  alert($('#take').val()); 
                   });
              });  
         </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `bind` is deprecated, and I suspect you're only using it because you couldn't get `on` to work. The reason that you can't get it to work is because the `change` event doesn't trigger simply because a change is made in the box. It only triggers after the box loses focus.

So, if you programmatically change the value in a box, the `change` event doesn't trigger at all, since it never had focus in the first place.

The way to get what you want is to also programmatically trigger the change event, like so (I went ahead and replaced your `bind` with `on`, and changed your `click` event to a `change` event as it should be):

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(function() {
            $('#cat_id').on('change', function() {

              var s = $('#cat_id').val();
              var n = s.lastIndexOf(",");
              var s2 = s.substring(n + 1);

              $('#take').val(s2).trigger('change');
            })
          });

          $('#take').on('change', function(e) {
            $('#give').val($('#take').val());

          });

        });
```

To get a clearer understanding of how the `change` event works, have a look at [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_change_ref).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Finally i fixed my issue...kindly vote up my question.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what exactly you want to achieve, if you want to bind your selection of  options you should use "change" instead of click in your jquery code 
[link + example](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

if you are interested to bind your textbox you should use select instead of click

[link + example](https://api.jquery.com/select/)

**update**

A small example of triggering events

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    var selectedOption = '';
  $("#optionSelect").change(function (e) {
        selectedOption = $( "#optionSelect option:selected" ).text();
        $("#testBtn").trigger("click");
   });

   $("#testBtn").click(function (e){
        $("#first_input").val(selectedOption);
   });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="optionSelect">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>

<button id='testBtn'>Test me</button>

<div id='test'></div>
<input type='text' id='first_input'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir, I want that when i select any of category name (A,B,C), the value goes to my "FIRST INPUT" on updataion of that value , I want to trigger a event...

Comment: sir, i want that , as you have the option, when you select one option, the the value of that option goes to a input box, on that instant as the inputbox value  update/change an event will trigger with change of that input box value, I hope know you understand it ?

Comment: @Newbees So trigger it! But you have to do it yourself. This answer is the concept you're looking for, applied to a different situation. Perhaps between this answer and mine you'll have it figured out. :)

Comment: Yeah I noticed, I changed the alert to put a value in a textbox instead

Comment: I'm really thankful for your time and effort but the issue is already fixed.